# Magento Duplicate Loading of JS CSS files

Tags: javascript, php, css, magento

When checking the Web-page performance I came across some finding by GTmetrix that some CSS & JS files are being loaded from different locations - the same file.
Example:

```
<action method="addItem" module="ves_blockbuilder" ifconfig="ves_blockbuilder/ves_blockbuilder/enable_animation"><type>skin_css</type><name>ves_base/animate.css</name></action>

<action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/animate.css</name><params/></action>
```

This what is shown is page source.

```
skin/frontend/ves_value/default/css/animate.css" media="all" />

skin/frontend/base/default/ves_base/animate.css" media="all" />
```

my question is how I can safely avoid one from loading without affecting any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options:

1. You can remove one of the `<action method="addItem">` lines.
2. In the System Configuration, you can turn off animation in
   the `ves_blockbuilder` settings. The attribute
   `ifconfig="ves_blockbuilder/ves_blockbuilder/enable_animation"`
   means that the the css file will be added only if the `enable_animation` 
   setting is set to `true/yes/enabled/etc`. However, if you need the animation 
   module for other functionality, then I'd keep this and remove the bottom 
   line.

*An additional note: make sure they're the exact same file. It's possible that they have the same filename, but different css rules -- in which case it's valid to keep both files.*